# Socket on android pie or api level 28 is not working. I'm not able to connect with Socket using host and post in android java

Tags: java, android, sockets, kotlin, socket.io

I tried with this code

```
try {
  pingSocket = Socket(host, port)
  out = PrintWriter(pingSocket.getOutputStream(), true)
  br = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(pingSocket.getInputStream()))
} catch (e: IOException) {
  return null
}

Log.d("xx", "Locating Slot...")

while (true) {
  resp = br.readLine().toString()
  Log.d("xx", "Reader's Telnet Data: " + resp)
}
```

This code is working on below android 9.0. I also added `network-security-config.xml` file under xml directory and added `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in `manifest.xml` file.
While I'm testing on android pie the cursor stops at `pingSocket = Socket(host, port)` line and throws a timeout exception.

Comment: Tell about host and port please.

Comment: Does it work on 9?

Comment: @blackapps it's not working on 9 and above but working fine below 9. I think something is wrong with api level 28+